# How to make grid view full responsive

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm developing an Android application I need to install this app on different devices, for this reason i need that the layout is full responsive.

One of my activity it consist in a grid view with two columns, each column it consist in a "square" (a image).

The problem is that i can't adapt the play for all devices (small, normal, large, etc).

```
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent();

                switch (position) {

                    case 0:
                        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Bacheca.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Turni.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Utility.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Contatti.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ScriviBacheca.class);
                        i.putExtra("user_id", id_user);
                        i.putExtra("nome", cognome);
                        i.putExtra("cognome", nome);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Info.class);
                        i.putExtra("user_id", id_user);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        connectivityMessage("Nessuna connessione presente, assicurati di avere il traffico dati oppure il Wi-Fi attivato e riprova.");
    }
}



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

            int screenLayout = getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
            screenLayout &= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

            switch (screenLayout) {
                case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
                    break;

                case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(330, 330));

                    break;

                case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(280, 280));

                    break;

                case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
                    break;

                default:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
                    break;
            }




        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.bacheca, R.drawable.turni,
            R.drawable.utility, R.drawable.contatti,
            R.drawable.invia, R.drawable.info
    };
}
```

this is the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="am.pacrocebianca.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This solution works for normal and large devices but doesn't work for small devices, because the layout is the same of normal layout.

This is the list of the devices that i use to debug my app:

Small phone : Sony Xperia U (3,5'')

Normal phone: Motorola moto G 2014 (5'')

Large: Tablet Acer A1-713 (7'')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change `android:numColumns="2"` to `android:numColumns="auto_fit"`
Your `GridView` will display as many columns as possible to fill the available space.

```
<GridView
    ...
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
/>
```

Comment: Ok, another quastion, if i want "adapt" my image automatically ??

In my code i have specify:

 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));

Is it correct ? For me is hardcoded and this is not a good choise

Comment: if you don't want to hardcoded . just calculate the screensize programmatically. then your image view size will equals : (screensize / numberOfColumn)